# How do you detect if AutoCAD is done plotting in AutoLISP

Tags: python, autocad, win32com, autolisp

Is there a way to figure out if a plot job is still working in AutoLISP?

I am currently using the `DWG To PDF.pc3` printer in a LISP script in AutoCAD 2007. Unfortunately, the `vla-PlotToFile` function returns immediately. I would like to automatically open the file upon completion of the plot.

If it helps, I am actually doing a lot of the coding outside of AutoCAD in Python, calling into it with win32com.

The code I currently have is:

```
(vla-PlotToFile (vla-get-Plot activeDocument) printing-filename "DWG To PDF.pc3")
```

That returns before AutoCAD has finished plotting.

I considered checking for the existence of the pdf file after that command, but often times, I write over that file, so it already exists before the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off background plotting by setting the BACKGROUNDPLOT system variable to zero. See e.g. [this blog post](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/06/backgroundplot-system-variable.html).

Comment: I had found that enironment variable, but it was already set to 2, which is foreground for plots and background for publishing. I thought that was good enough. Thanks.